# sum of column based on distinct value of other column in Oracle

Tags: oracle

**Table A**

```
A1 A2
1  7
2  8
1  9
```

**Table B**

```
A1 B2
1  2
2  3
```

i want something like this

```
select A.A1,sum(case when distinct A.A1 then B2),sum(A.A2) from
A,B
where A.A1=B.A1(+)
group by A.A1
```

After joining my table will be

```
A1  A2  B2
1   7   2
2   8   3
1   9   2
```

Resulting Table

```
A1  A2    B2
1   7+9   2(only once)
2   8     3
```

how to get sum of B2 when distinct A1 after joining the tables as stated above.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: is table_b.a1 unique?

Comment: You are using an out-dated join syntax. Are you forced to work on a very old Oracle version or is it just that you were given a very old book to learn from? Use proper explicit ANSI joins instead if possible (`from a left outer join b on a.a1 = b.a1`).

Comment: @Boneist yes it is unique and refers to table_a.a1

Comment: And given the sample data you provided, what are you expecting the output to be?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner just found readability point of view old syntax was good, any way thanks.

Comment: In the Question i have provided **Resulting Table** after joining.
from that i want sum(A2)=7+8+9(sum all the rows) and sum(B2)=2+3(should sum only for unique A1)

Answer (score 0):

Use `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`.

**Query**

```
SELECT t1.A1, SUM(t1.A2) AS A1, SUM(t2.B2) AS B2
FROM TableA t1
JOIN TableB t2
ON t1.A1 = t2.A1
GROUP BY t1.A1;
```

Comment: I want the same with left outer join. can u provide solution without sub query. Any possibility with conditional sum?

Comment: @SiddeshwarGajula : conditional sum in the sense?

Comment: select A.A1,**sum(case when distinct A.A1 then B2)**,sum(A.A2) 
fromA,B
where A.A1=B.A1(+)
group by A.A1

though the syntax is not  correct just for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Since table_b.a1 is unique, the best way to do this would be to work out the sum of table_a.a2 first to reduce the number of rows you're joining against, and then join to table_b. Then you don't need to worry about summing the distinct table_b.b2 values, which you would otherwise have to do.

```
WITH table_a AS (SELECT 1 a1, 7 a2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 2 a1, 8 a2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 a1, 9 a2 FROM dual),
     table_b AS (SELECT 1 a1, 2 b2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 2 a1, 3 b2 FROM dual)
-- end of mimicking your two tables with sample_data in them;
-- see the sql below:
SELECT ta.a1,
       ta.a2,
       tb.b2
FROM   (SELECT   a1, SUM(a2) a2
        FROM     table_a
        GROUP BY a1) ta
       INNER JOIN table_b tb ON ta.a1 = tb.a1;

        A1         A2         B2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         16          2
         2          8          3
```

---

If you absolutely must join the two tables first (I don't recommend; this is making more work for the database to do), then you could do something like:

```
WITH table_a AS (SELECT 1 a1, 7 a2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 2 a1, 8 a2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 a1, 9 a2 FROM dual),
     table_b AS (SELECT 1 a1, 2 b2 FROM dual UNION ALL
                 SELECT 2 a1, 3 b2 FROM dual)
SELECT   ta.a1,
         SUM(ta.a2) a2,
         MAX(tb.b2) b2
FROM     table_a ta
         INNER JOIN table_b tb ON ta.a1 = tb.a1
GROUP BY ta.a1;

        A1         A2         B2
---------- ---------- ----------
         1         16          2
         2          8          3
```

Since there can only be one distinct value for table_b.b2 per table_a.a1, we can just pick one of the values to use via `MAX` (we could have used `MIN` or `SUM(distinct tb.b2)` instead, fyi).

Comment: Thanks for the solution.